# Check if first item in array is empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have seen dozens of questions asked for checking if an array is empty. But I can't find the question on how to check if the first item in an array is empty.

Currently, I am doing this check on this way, but I highly doubt that it is the correct way to do this.

```js
var specialtiesListArray = ['', 'not', 'empty', 'value'];

if (specialtiesListArray[0] == '') {
    
    specialtiesListArray.shift(); // <== Removing the first item when empty.

}

console.info({ specialtiesListArray });
```

The above works fine, but I am wondering is this ok? Are there better ways. And if someone knows a duplicate, then please let me know. I gladly delete the question if it has already been answered.

Comment: `pd.isnull(x) or not bool(x)` would be pretty good at finding empty values.

Comment: it's good. I don't see any problem with keeping this code as it is, it is simple and clear to understand

Comment: The code is fine as it is, there isn't any noticeable problem. My only piece of advice is to use `===` in place of `==`, in this way if you have empty arrays or zeros it won't delete the element. Remember that in JS `[] == ''` or `0 == ''` are true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is just fine. You could create a function, and check array length before trying to read element at index `0`:

- utils.js

```
export const removeFirstItemIfEmpty = (array) => {
    if (array.length > 0 && array[0] == '') {
        array.shift();
    }
    return array;
}
```

```
import { removeFirstItemIfEmpty } from './utils.js'

const result = removeFirstItemIfEmpty(['', 'not', 'empty', 'value']);
console.info({ result });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter` and update the array.

```js
specialtiesListArray = ['', 'not', 'empty', 'value'];
specialtiesListArray = specialtiesListArray.filter((item, index) => index!==0 && item !== '');
console.log(specialtiesListArray);
```

Comment: This would remove not just the first element

Comment: this does not remove the empty elements, but it creates a new array (without them) which replaces the original array...

Comment: @BrunoPolo - Now it does :)

Comment: @GuruprasadJRao if verification is only needed in first element, there is no need to check all items in array (Array.filter will loop through all items)

Answer (score 0):

The following function will remove anything that is undefined, null or empty but will allow the number `0` to pass:

```js
var testArr = [['', null, 'not', 'empty', 'value'],[false,2,3,4],[undefined,"", null,"one","two"],[0,1,2,3]];

function ltrimArr(arr){
 while (arr.length && !arr[0]&&arr[0]!==0) arr.shift();
 return arr
}

testArr.forEach(a=>console.log(ltrimArr(a)))
```